# thymeleaf and spring 3.0

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I've a form in which on click of add button a new row would come up. if again add button is clicked another row Will come up below the previous one and so on.
the user Will enter information in these rows. 
my problem is how to pass the value of the newly added information in each row to the spring controller .

Answer (score 0):

Your rows elements should named as a list to be binded in a list object in your controller.
example:

```
<input type="text" name="address[0]" />
<input type="text" name="address[1]" />
[...]
```

So, when you add a new row, just increment the address index.

Hope it answer your question.